# Boolean always outputs true

Tags: java, loops, if-statement, boolean

I have a class to test a palindrome.  In my loop, it compares each letter to see if they match, if they don't, it's supposed to make the boolean variable as false, or vice versa.  Now I've tested it a ton, and I can see that if I correctly put in a palindrome, it actually goes to the correct if statement which makes the variable true.  If it comes across a pair of letters which don't match, it's supposed to declare the boolean variable as false and break from the loop, which it actually does properly.  But no matter what, the boolean variable is always true when I try to use it to determine what response comes back, and I have no idea why.

```
 is a palindrome!  Hooray!
```

is ALWAYS the output, even if the loop goes to the false boolean and breaks, and it baffles me.

```
public class Palindrome
{
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    //is it true?
    boolean truth;
    //create stack and queue
    Stack s = new Stack();
    Queue q = new LinkedList();
    //scanner
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    //get string
    System.out.println("Enter a palindrome, or don't, I'll know:");
    String palin = input.nextLine();
    //remove whitespace
    palin = palin.replaceAll("\\s+","");
    System.out.println(palin);
    //remove puncuation
    palin = palin.replaceAll("\\p{P}", "");
    System.out.println(palin);
    //set lowercase
    palin = palin.toLowerCase();
    System.out.println(palin);

    //feed string to stack and queue
    for(int i = 0; i < palin.length(); i++)
    {
        s.push(palin.charAt(i));
        q.add(palin.charAt(i));
    }
    System.out.println(s);
    System.out.println(q);
    while(!s.isEmpty() && !q.isEmpty())
    {
        Object sTemp = s.pop();
        Object qTemp = q.poll();
        String sString = sTemp.toString();
        String qString = qTemp.toString();
        System.out.println(sString + qString);
        System.out.println("looptest");
        if(sString.equals(qString))
        {
            truth = true;
        }
        else
        {
            truth = false;
            break;
        }
    }
    if(truth = true)
    {
        System.out.println(palin + " is a palindrome!  Hooray!");
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(palin + " is no palindrome! You lied!");
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Why do you make your algorithm so complex?

Answer (score 7):

With this line

```
if(truth = true)
```

You are assigning `true` to `truth` with `=`, when you probably meant `==` to compare.  It's already a `boolean`, so just have it as the condition.

```
if (truth)
```

Answer (score -1):

basic ,but most programmer(beginner) tend to typo-error or just dont know the difference of 
`=` and `==` or meet them officially, so here it goes

`=` is assignment operator and
`==` test for equality or conditional operator

so in your line

```
 if(truth = true)
    {
       ...
    }
```

you are assigning your variable `truth` to have `true` as value

Gotta use the `==` so value of your boolean wont change.

```
if(truth == true)
    {
      ...
    }
```

or

```
if(truth.equals(true))
    {
       ...
    }
```

Comment: Do note that this answer is incorrect because you can't use `truth.equals(true)`, it will not compile due to primitive types not having a `.equals()` method